# Upgrading Multibit (without losing wallet)

Tags: multibit

I am using Multibit 0.4.23 but would like to install Multibit 0.5.9.  How would I move my coins from my current wallet? Is this done automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much every single program allows you to upgrade it without losing data, and Multibit almost certainly isn't exception.

Just upgrade it.

In case you're worried, backup your wallet first.